# The prp() function from rpart in R only plots a single leaf node. Why?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, decision-tree, rpart

I am learning how to code in R for machine learning. I am using rpart to do the heavy lifting. However, when I go to plot my decision tree, only a leaf node 'yes' is plotted. I've created the decision tree myself by hand using information gain. The tree should have three levels of nodes.

[image: decision tree by hand]

Here is what R gives me.

[image: decision tree plot from rpr()]

Here is my R code.

```
library(FSelector)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(data.tree)
library(caTools)
table <- read.csv("play-data.csv")
table <- select(table, Outlook, Temperature, Humidity, Windy, Play)
table <- mutate(table, Outlook = factor(Outlook), Temperature = factor(Temperature), Humidity = factor(Humidity), Play = factor(Play))
tree <- rpart(Play ~ Outlook + Temperature + Humidity + Windy, data = table)
prp(tree)
```

Here is the data from 'play-data.csv'.

[image: play-data.csv]

The data is being read in correctly, and the selection and mutation functions seem to be fine as well. So I don't know what gives. I tried Googling the problem but only found one other thread about it with no concise answer that I can understand.

Comment: If you just type `tree`,  what do you get?  It should give you a text version of the decision tree. Does that just have one node?

Comment: @G5W This is what I get in the console output: 1) root 14 5 yes (0.3571429 0.6428571) *

Comment: So the tree that you produced just has the one node.  The problem is not with `prp`. It is correctly displaying your single node. The problem is - why are you getting just one node in your decision tree.

Comment: make some adjustments to the parameters in `?rpart.control`

Comment: @G5W I see. Well the problem has to be with the rpart() function then because the table looks fine after the mutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a tree with a single node because you are using the default settings for  `rpart`. The documentation is a little indirect. The documentation tells you that there is a parameter called `control` and says "See rpart.control."  If you click through to the documentation for rpart.control, you will see that there is a parameter called `minsplit` which is described as "the minimum number of observations that must exist in a node in order for a split to be attempted."   The default value is 20 and you only have 14 data points altogether. It will not split the root node. Instead,  use `rpart.control` to set `minsplit` to a lower value (try 2).